# Mapping postgresql geometry column to field in java object

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, postgis

I have created a table in postgresql as:

```
CREATE TABLE feature (ID serial, feature_name text, geom geometry(GEOMETRYZ,4326));
```

I have to read the data using spring's reactive support for relational databases(r2dbc).
I am not sure how to map geom column to a field in java class.

My incomplete class is:

```
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Table
public class Feature {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column("feature_name")
    private String featureName;

    @Column("geom")
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    public com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry geom;
}
```

What java datatype would map to postgresql geometry? How to do it?

Edit:
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect

Error is in code:

```
FeatureRepository featureRepository = applicationContext.getBean(FeatureRepository.class);
        featureRepository.findAll().doOnNext(feature -> {
            log.info(feature.toString());
        }).blockLast(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

Comment: Hey there. In which format do you want to have your geometry? WKT, GeoJSON, KML, etc..

Comment: I am looking for GeoJSON.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with spring-boot, but if you can pass a function to the column `geom` you could try `ST_AsGeoJSON(geom)`. I've also seen this syntax before: `@Column(name = "geom", columnDefinition = "geometry(Point,4326)")`

Answer (score 1):

Use [com.vividsolutions.jts.geom](http://javadox.com/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.13/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/package-summary.html).

Here I am giving an example of `Point`

```
@Column("geom")
private Point location;
```

And you can create `Point` using `GeometryFactory`

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(12.34343, 12.232424));
```

Add `hibernate-spatial` in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Then you need to add dialect depending on your PostgreSQL

```
org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG9Dialect
```

Comment: I have field as Geometry, and it gives error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required identifier property not found for class com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry!

Comment: @Column("geom")

    @Type(type="org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")

    public com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry geom;

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect

Comment: What is your PostgreSQL version ? When you are getting error saving ?

Comment: Its Postgresql 12, and I get error when I read records. Records are already there in the database table. I am using spring boot r2dbc support.

Comment: Use `org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG9Dialect` or other compatible with postgresql verstion

Comment: And I am using without @Type annotation its perfectly working

Comment: I am still facing issue. So I changed a bit:
@Query(value = "select id, feature_name, st_asgeojson(geom) from feature")
    Flux<Feature> getAllFeatures();
This causes Feature objects to have first 2 fields with correct values, but geom is null.

Comment: What happend if you call like method naming query `findById` ? (Just thinking is there any issue with quering or not)

Comment: Tried that too, same error. Can you please tell me your dialect, and entity class and pom dependencies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215588/discussion-between-eklavya-and-mandroid).

Comment: I was using spring r2dbc. That seems has the issue in mapping. Now I am using spring jpa.It works fine.

Comment: Great finally it's working! You can voluntarily raise an issue in spring r2dbc. I was using spring jpa, but don't think that  will cause problem

Comment: yup, raised. Thanks for all the inputs.